# Кинуть и бросить

Tags: семантика, лексика

Есть ли какая-то смысловая разница (возможно, оттенки смысла или настроения) между словами "кинуть" и "бросить"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Словари особой смысловой разницы не дают, но навскидку: "бросить" более нейтрально и шире по значению. Если прицельно или с целью какого результата - то скорее бросить. 
В спортивной терминологии (легкая атлетика, единоборства) только "бросить".
Хотя у "кидать" тоже есть какие-то значения, в которых "бросить" менее употребимо. Кидаться грязью, например. Или накидать (товар) в сумку.

Comment: Есть еще множество переносных значений.

Comment: Особой массы не знаю. 
Бросил жену с детьми да кинул на бабки.

Comment: Бросил курить. (Не) бросайся словами.  
Вспоминается, что про эти два слова был вопрос на олимпиаде Ломоносова (или другой какой?). Ответ был весьма развернутым.

Comment: Не берусь спорить предметно, но я бы эти значения не выделял. Ну или не не отделял бы от того, что я дал.   
А "развернутые" ответы - беда всех подобных вопросов. Многословие с учспехом заменяет систематику и структурированность. Это мне знакомо... Лениво больше писатать, надеюсь в данном случае я не остался опять непоянятым.

Comment: Ладно, не буду отделять. Но "кинул курить" и "кидается словами" - все же не говорят.

Comment: @DocentI, умоляю, хоть вы не заражайтесь этой болезнью.)))
Ну разве кто-то предлагал "кинуть курить"? Я предлягал не отделять "бросить курить" от "бросить жену", ибо смысл тот же.    
"Кидаться словами" - вполне себе употребительный вариант.

Comment: Я же с Вами согласилась.

Comment: Простите, не врспринял как согласие.  
С этой чертовщиной на форуме... 
Вроде и Хэллоуин прошел, в ведьмы всё резвятся...

Answer (score 0):

Не профессионально, но как я понимаю.
"Кинуть" — антоним "вынуть". Как мне кажется, есть общий смысл также со словом "внутрь". Если обобщить, то НУТ — это пустота... Иначе, тот же смысл другими словами, — бросить в пустоту, взять из пустоты, попасть в пустоту. В общем, перемещение чего-либо вниз или в никуда.
Бросить, сбросить, забросить, подбросить... Не могу объяснить, но разница с семейством "кинуть" чувствуется.
Если выбирать («подбросить дров» или «подкинуть дров»), то правильней будет, как мне кажется, «подкинуть дров»...